# URL rewrite not working

Tags: url, config, siteurl, setup

For some reason the CraftCMS URL rewrite is not working on GoDaddy shared hosting server.

Currently by .htaccess file looks like this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Has anyone encountered this problem? Can someone help me solve this?

**Update**

I am not sure any more if this a url rewrite problem. As when I access an entry such as http://aspaceboydream.com/comic/so-this-is-me, it loads correctly. But when I use the function:

```
url('comic')
```

to construct the urls of the different channels, the URLs are being constructed as http://aspaceboydream.com/index.php?p=comic

Answer (score 9):

I solved the problem and am writing it down for future people encountering the same problem.

Add the following configuration to the your `craft/config/general.php` config file:

```
'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true
```

URLs will start to work fine.

Comment: this does not affect actionUrl method it seems...

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** Quick answer (as per [RitterKnight's](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/users/1016/ritterknight) comment)... just add `RewriteBase /` to the top of your **.htaccess** file in the root of your public/public_html directory.

---

I am on the same type of shared GoDaddy server, and continued to experience the same issue regardless of wether 'omitScriptNameInUrls' was set to true. I would get an "Internal Server Error" on all pages, apart from the homepage.

I have since [found a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101600/htaccess-not-working-on-godaddy/23519720#23519720) which is specifically tailored to GoDaddy sufferers. My .htaccess file now looks like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews -Indexes   

RewriteBase /

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Success! I now have a Craft installation on a GoDaddy shared server, with clean-urls working!

Comment: I'm guessing the addition of the line ``RewriteBase /`` is what's making this work. IIRC the last time I used GoDaddy, it ignored ``DirectoryIndex`` and used index.php as the default anyway but YMMV.

You don't need the ``RewriteEngine On`` directive in there twice—you have it once in the ``IfModule`` block—where it usually is—and again above it, outside the block. By convention, ``RewriteBase /`` usually sits below inside the ``ifModule`` block on the off chance mod_rewrite is turned off or not installed.

Answer (score 3):

I have lord knows how many sites on GoDaddy (too many). The key to it is `RewriteBase`. Just add it to the default `.htaccess` and you're all set.

Comment: Nice, thank you. So those first 4 lines in my comment are unnecessary.